# Does $\pi_1(S^1)\approx \mathbb{Z}$ mean the same thing as $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation

In Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), one of the first results encountered is that the fundamental group of the circle, $\pi_1(S^1)$, is isomorphic to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. notated in the book as $\pi_1(S^1)\approx\mathbb{Z}$.

However, in other documents I have found online (take the solution to problem 16 (a) in this [document](http://tarunchitra.com/papers/6510/hw2.pdf), for instance), I keep seeing the equality ($=$) symbol in the place of the isomorphic ($\approx$) symbol, i.e. instead of $\pi_1(S^1)\approx\mathbb{Z}$ it is written as $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

So my question is:  which is it?  That is, what notation is technically correct?  Or are they both correct?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing. Really, the equal sign is not correct, because $\pi_1$, as a set, cointains element of type $[\gamma]$, i.e class of homotopic equivalent paths, _not numbers_. When you see an equal sign followed by a number group, really it's a isomorphism. Even if the paper you linked, sometime the author uses the equal sign, sometime the isomorphism sign.

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo Yeah I noticed that they used both notations, which is why I was even more confused!  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good article about 'equality': [Mazur - When is one thing equal to some other thing.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf)

Comment: That was a fantastic read, and was exactly what I needed to see.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not equality, just isomorphisim. Equality is a much stronger property (of sets) while isomorphism just means equivalence in that current category you're in (so groups for your case).

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wanted to make sure!  Thanks for the answer.